# How to run JUnit test cases in play framework 2.3.2

Tags: junit, playframework, sbt, playframework-2.3, typesafe-activator

I have made eclipse project of play application. I am developing java app, not using scala.

There were default test cases under test source folder under default package. Class name is ApplicationTest

I have read about how to write test cases using JUnit. Default test cases are written using same way. I run my app using activator, But not able to run test cases. Could not find much information about it.

In activator console test command shows 0 test cases. Following is the outout

```
mindt@hridayesh:content-engine$ ./activator
[info] Loading project definition from /home/mindt/gitrepo/content-engine/project
[info] Set current project to Content-Engine (in build file:/home/mindt/gitrepo/content-engine/)
[Content-Engine] $ test
[info] Compiling 4 Java sources to /home/mindt/gitrepo/content-engine/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[success] Total time: 4 s, completed 30 Aug, 2014 6:03:50 PM
[Content-Engine] $ testOnly
[info] Compiling 4 Java sources to /home/mindt/gitrepo/content-engine/target/scala-2.11/classes...
[info] Passed: Total 0, Failed 0, Errors 0, Passed 0
[info] No tests to run for test:testOnly
[success] Total time: 2 s, completed 30 Aug, 2014 6:03:55 PM
[Content-Engine] $
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution with `activator clean` sometimes doesn't work when Eclipse is running. Closing Eclipse and then peforming `activator clean` afterwards worked for me.

Answer (score 2):

did activator clean and it started working.

```
./activator clean
```